# FileIO in System Verilog for floating point numbers

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

My "input.txt" has floating point numbers (signed) . I want to read this in IEEE floating point format, convert it into binary and write it to file(temp_out.txt). read this binary representation and interpret it again as floating point number. and print it in output.txt. (both the input.txt and output.txt should match). 
input.txt has:-

```
1.234
-1.234
1.23e5
-1.23e5
```

I see value after decimal point gets lost for 1.234. OR output is all 0 for others.

```
module abc;
    integer fp;
    shortreal val,valout;
    bit[31:0] valb;

    initial  begin
        $display("Start");  
        fp = $fopen("input.txt","r");
        while (! $feof(fp))begin
            $fscanf(fp,"%f",val);
            $display("in %f",val);
            // NEED to get this right . this is what I have already tried.
            //valb = $realtobits(val);
            //valb = val;
            //$cast(valb,val);
            $display("b %b",valb);    
            $display("f %f",$bitstoreal(valb));
            // valout = valb;
            valout = $bitstoreal(valb);
            $display("fout %f",valout);
            $display("---------------------");
        end
        $display("end");  
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$realtobits()` and `$bitstoreal()` but the varibles are defined as `shortreal` and `bit [31:0]`.  `$realtobits()` and `$bitstoreal()` expect the real to be a `real` and the bits to be `bit [63:0]`

SystemVerilog has `$shortrealtobits()` and `$bitstoshortreal()` to work with `shortreal`.

`shortreal` and the shortreal system functions do not exist in Verilog.